# Does detached thread leaks memory C++ after exit

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory-leaks, detach

I have an use case where I have to stop the thread from within itself. So I was thinking to detach it and once the call the stop method (which would complete the execution of the thread).

So does it leak memory after detach ? If so, how should this be handled ?

Comment: Detaching threads and threads possibly leaking memory are orthogonal to each other.

Comment: I mean to ask, when will the detached thread release the resources. What happens if it doesn't release at all ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "stop" a specific thread that is detached unless the thread actually exits (e.g. `return`s), so it depends on what you mean. At least, this is not possible with standard C++ threads.

If you are asking whether a thread that `return`s will *automatically* clean up resources, the answer is no -- it will not. Any RAII objects that clean up resources in their *destructors* will be called, but anything explicitly allocated will not be cleaned up and will require code to do this manually.

If you are thinking of something like `pthread_cancel`, then most likely it will *not* be cleaned up since this is a C API and cancellation does not insert a `return` that performs destructor cleanup. I strongly advise against doing this sort of thing.

If by "stop"ing from the thread you actually mean something like `std::exit`, then this is dependent on the underlying operating system you are using. Destructors will not be run, so any specific clean up code will not be performed; however on most modern OSes any used resources like open memory will be cleaned up on program termination. However, there are some systems out there that don't do this (usually specialized/embedded RTOS)

---

The best way to prevent any type of leak with a detached thread is to be able to signal to it when you want it to complete, and to always use RAII objects so that cleanup will be automatic.

With [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) you can actually use [`std::stop_token`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_token) for this, but in anything before that you can simply devise a synchronization system from a `std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<bool>>` and querying this within the thread as a "cancellation point".

Comment: From : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/detach/
"""Detaches the thread represented by the object from the calling thread, allowing them to execute independently from each other.

Both threads continue without blocking nor synchronizing in any way. Note that when either one ends execution, its resources are released."""

It says, the resources are released during execution. What does this mean ?

My use case is, I want to stop a thread explicitly, so I am doing detcah() + return. Does this seem right ?

Comment: That point is referring to both `thread_local` data, and the thread object itself (which is a systems resource). As long as a thread is properly returning _eventually_, and as long everything else in the code is leak-free (e.g. no naked `new` calls, always use RAII types like containers, smart-pointers, etc), then you should be fine.

Comment: What it _won't_ cover is if you were to do something like `auto* p = new int; return` in your thread function, since this memory will not be `delete`d and would be a leak. Or similarly if this thread opened a socket or a file, but failed to close it. The only resources the thread will automatically take care of are thread resources; but anything doing manual resource management won't automatically be cleaned up